# Google Analytics: Using ga() functions with GTAG

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I was using the old `analytics.js` to insert Google Analytics on my website. But now I'm trying to upgrade to Google Site Tag (GTAG). I understand that GTAG is just a wrapper for Google Analytics and the same analytics.js is being loaded by GTAG. I have quite a few custom event functions written using the `ga()` function that `analytics.js` provided. They were working fine with `analytics.js` but with GTAG I no longer can use those. GTAG has its own `gtag()` functions and if I try to use `ga()` function with GTAG, I get the "ga is not defined" error.

My question is, how can or even can I use the old `ga()` functions with GTAG without having to update the code.

Comment: Read this article from google to use gtag.js https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gtagjs/sending-data

Comment: I have already.I know that I can send custom event via gtag(), but what I wanted to know was that if GTAG is loading the same analytics.js, how can I use the old ga() function.

Comment: gtag() and ga() use different parameters. So I can't just swap ga() with gtag().

Comment: don't swap but to use side by side. both are serving two different purposes. if adding gtag.js didn't resolve your problem, then let me know.

Comment: The problem is that I can't use ga() functions with GTAG. I get the "ga is not defined" error. So I can't use them side by side.

Comment: Looking at this code will give you some prospective:

`<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=G-XXXXXX"></script>
<script>
    window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
    function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
    gtag('js', new Date());
    ga( 'send', 'event', 'category', 'action', 'label' );
    gtag('config', 'G-XXXXXX');
</script>`

Comment: You can replace the above ga code with a tag like, 
<!-- Global Site Tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=GA_MEASUREMENT_ID"></script>
<script>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());

  gtag('config', 'GA_MEASUREMENT_ID');
</script>

Comment: Your code does not sends custom events.

Comment: Here is a guide to replace the ga tag with tag code from google: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/upgrade/analyticsjs#analyticsjs_2_gtagjs

Comment: Is this help you?

Comment: That is my problem. gtag() is a complete rewrite. I don't want to rewrite the entire code from ga() to gtag(). That is why I'm looking for a way to use the old ga() function with GTAG.

Comment: Dear, this is not possible/implementable.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that GTag somehow uses ga() function after all: After I inserted the new GTag code and removed old Google Analytics code, I also tried to deactivate old GA custom events that may existed at various points of my website, by defining a "trap" function for ga() calls:

```
function ga(){
    return false;
}
```

However, this resulted to making GTag not working properly (gtag() functions did not work).

Comment: At the minimum you should edit the existing calls to ga by wrapping them with the condition `if (typeof ga !== 'undefined') { // your old code }`. Maybe also installing both ga and gtag could work. The real solution is either a rewrite, or installing a tag manager so you just call events from the code and define the syntax in the tag manager: in this way you're ready for the next rewrite